# How to set break lines in console log for multiple values

Tags: jquery

There is multiple select boxes class named .ex and i am trying to see them on console log.How can i add spaces between them?

```
console.log($('.ex').find(':selected').text());
```

Comment: Please share some example data or screenshot to better understand your question.

Comment: What is a "select box" and what `text` does it have? Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54761332/edit) and then `[<>]` the snippet editor and provide us with a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could "reverse" your approach. Log text for each element.

```
$('.ex')
  .find(':selected')
  .each(function(){
    console.log($(this).text())
  })
```

Comment: @mplungjan Do you mean `.ex :selected`? Might be.

Comment: I likely meant `$('.ex:checked')` without the space - but what is a selectbox anyway?

Comment: But `.ex:checked` is not the same selector as `$('.ex')` and then `find(':selected')`. Since original approach worked ok I've decided not to change OP's selector :). But you might be right depending on actual HTML OP has.

Answer (score 0):

Map each to their text, then join by newlines (or by whatever separator you want):

```
const output = [...$('.ex').find(':selected')]
  .map(elm => elm.textContent)
  .join('\n');
```

Note that `.text()` will only return to you the text of the *first* matching element, thus the use of `.map` instead.

Comment: Sure, you could also use jQuery's `.map`, but you'd have to use `.get()` at the end to extract the array from it. Either works.